# jQuery and Bootstrap autocomplete javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4

I am having trouble getting an autocomplete function to work.
The object is created at the top of the page:

```
<script>
  var equipment = [
    <?php
      foreach (fmsValueListItems2($FMTimesheet, 'fake_timesheet', 'All Values', "", null, "") as $list_item) {
        if (html_entity_decode($list_item[0]) == "") {

        } else {
          echo "{value:\"{$list_item[0]}\",label:\"{$list_item[1]}\"},";
        }
      }
    ?>
  ];
</script>
```

And I stringify this object and add it to a div:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
  var myJSON = JSON.stringify(equipment);
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = myJSON;
</script>
```

It spits out something like this:

```
{"value":"x10B1","label":"Company Bobcat"}, 
{"value":"08003","label":"08003 John Doe"},
{"value":"08007","label":"08007 Jane Doe"},...
```

And so on for a few hundred values.

I can't get an autocomplete function to parse the object and push the "label" into the input to be sent to the next page.

The autocomplete should output a list of the labels in my object.

Comment: Where is the jquery-ui?

Comment: Can you put in complete JSON output, jQuery UI Code